# Javascript, create new iframe copying contents from existing iframe and attach to body

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe which contains data from an local server. I want to copy or clone this iframe, including the contents and then update the contents so the `css`, `links` and `images` use absolute paths not relative. All of the contents is coming from a local server so no issue with CORS.

I'm try to do this to resolve an issue with html2canvas which I am using to create previews of the frame contents. I have it working for iframes where the content is using absolute paths, but when the iframe contents has relative paths the image is shown but hasn't been rendered correctly as the css, links and images aren't loaded.

So far I have the following:

```
// id of the iframe I want to copy
iframeId = obj.id

// id for the cloned iframe
cloneId = 'clone_' + iframeDoc

// read iframes document and clone iframe
iframeDocument = document.getElementById( iframeDoc ).contentDocument;
var clone = iframeDocument.cloneNode(true);

// update paths used
var css = clone.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
    css[i].href = css[i].href;
}
        
var img = clone.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].src = img[i].src;
}
            
var js = clone.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
    js[i].src = js[i].src;
}

// get html from clone
content = clone.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;                  

// create new frame and add to document
var newFrame = document.createElement( 'iframe' );
newFrame.id = cloneId
document.body.appendChild( newFrame ); 

// update contents of new iframe
var ifrm = document.getElementById( cloneId );
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write( content );
ifrm.document.close();


// generate preview
preview( test )

function preview( frame ) {
html2canvas( frame, ).then( function( canvas ) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL()
    // add img to preview window //
    });
}
```

Running this results in the error '`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document`' which is generated by the html2canvas function.

If I run console.log ( test ) just before the preview then the console shows `#document` which does contain all of the correct contents for the new iframe.

eg:

```
test = document.getElementById( cloneId ).contentDocument
console.log ( test )
```

Could some one advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `test` get its value assigned?

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my original post showing where `test` is assigned. Thanks